# Python - File writing and reading from a file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a file and write some text in it. 
Then I have to read the file before closing.I am trying out with the below code.

```
with open("newFile.txt",'w+') as f:
    f.write("Hi\nHello")
    a=f.read()
    print(a)
    f.close()
```

The above code create a file(newFile.txt) with the text Hi Hello.
But `a=f.read()`
 `print(a)` is not working. I am not able to read the file.What could be the reason?

Comment: You should get back to the beginning of the file before reading. Or, better yet, close the file and open it again for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read from file after write, before closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127960/read-from-file-after-write-before-closing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the file object needle to the first position, using seek():
Use this :

```py
with open("newFile.txt",'w+') as f:
 f.write("Hi\nHello")

 f.flush()
 f.seek(0)
 a=f.read()
 print(a)
 f.close()
```

Comment: The question has already been answered, do not multiply entities.

Comment: I tried with f.seek(0). It worked fine. May i know what is the use of flush() please