# How to count lines in file after adding new information?

Tags: python

I am beginner in Python.

I have file `example.txt`:

```
string1
```

I create simple code that count lines in this file:

```
fl = open('example.txt', 'r+')
lines = len(fl.readlines())
fl.write('string2\n')


print(lines)
```

I have problem: When I write one more line "string2" output gives me 1 even I have 2 lines in file, so python don't update info when i add some new information in file, what should I do?

```
Output:
    1
```

Comment: re-count the lines

Comment: You must update the variable "by hand": `lines += 1`

Comment: @rdas I don't know how to do it, could you explain to me please?

Comment: Why not run `lines = len(fl.readlines())` *after* you modify the file if you want the updated line count...?

Comment: I think you will need to do `fl.seek(0)` before reading the lines again to get the accurate count.  See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127960/read-from-file-after-write-before-closing

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the variable, that variable is set and done.

So:

```
fl = open('example.txt', 'r+')
lines = len(fl.readlines())
fl.write('string2\n')


print(lines)
```

Here you capture `len(fl.readlines())` (an integer of value 1) into your `lines` variable. And that's that. You can run hundreds of lines of code in between that an `print(lines)` and as long as you never re-set that variable to another value, it's going to output `1`.

If you want to capture the new line count, then you'll have to update that variable:

```
fl = open('example.txt', 'r+')
lines = len(fl.readlines())

print(lines) #prints 1

fl.write('string2\n')
lines = len(fl.readlines())

print(lines) #prints 2
```

Comment: I think you will need to execute `fl.seek(0)` prior to reading the lines again for an accurate count.